# NodeJs v0.10 vs 0.4

Tags: node.js

I am newbie to NodeJs and installed nodejs in ubuntu 15.04 using following command

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

I checked nodejs version

```
nodejs -v
v0.10.25
```

According to this link Node current version is **v4.2.1** https://nodejs.org/en/

What is difference between these two versions and how I can install v4.2.1 using terminal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're asking two unrelated questions. You should narrow your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install a package using apt-get you're depending on whatever the remote repositories for your package manager got. Depending on several factors they might be up to date or not. Generally speaking, they are *not* updated.

You can however:

- Use a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/ubuntu/node.js/)
- Download source and compile to install
- Use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

With the last option, you can choose what version to you, you can install io.js. But I guess these are topics further the *scope of the question* but you should read about it the way to get noticed of most recent Node's project status.

However you also asked about differences, so well, version 4.x are now long term support and are indeed result of the situation of the Node project and decisions at its community and the company behind Node.

The reason of this *big version leap* is just because Node used to have a 0.x based version scheme and now they merged it with another tight related project, io.js which strictly goes for semver versioning, so first version for the former was 1.0.

[This link is one of first results googling about versions differences.](http://apmblog.dynatrace.com/2015/09/05/all-you-need-to-know-about-node-js-4-0/)

Comment: Thanks. Installed latest version using nvm. :)